# Condition gave wrong data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I'm doing a MERN app, and I got stuck at this

I have an array, and I map over it, and after mapping over that array, I had to map over another array that was inside

So far, everything cool, everything working, but, I tried to put a condition, and, if that condition it's true, you're gonna show me some information, look at the code and the images

This is how de data looks like

[image]

And this is the code

```
import React from "react";

import { TodoMain, Todo, Close, CloseIcon, TaskContainer } from "./ToDoStyled";

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const ToDo = ({ setTodo, idRoom, setIdRoom }) => {
  const handleTodo = () => {
    setTodo(false);
    setIdRoom("");
    document.body.style = "overflow: auto";
  };

  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));

  const todo = useSelector(state =>
    state.tasks.filter(
      identificator => identificator.creator === user?.result?._id
    )
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <TodoMain>
        <Todo>
          <Close>
            <CloseIcon onClick={handleTodo} />
          </Close>
          <TaskContainer>
            {todo.map(data => {
              const { task, _id } = data;
              return (
                <div key={_id}>
                  {task.map(todo => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        {todo.room === idRoom && (
                          <h1 style={{ color: "white" }}>{todo.todo}</h1>
                        )}
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </TaskContainer>
        </Todo>
      </TodoMain>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ToDo;
```

So, what i did, was, if todo.room === idRoom then you're going to show me specific information, and the reason i'm doing it like that, it's because i don't want information from another room, that's why i made that condition

The weird thing, is that, if i put todo.room or todo.name, that works, but if i put todo.todo, it doesn't show me anything, so, what can i do so i can see me todo.todo stuff !?

Comment: It looks like some of your tasks don't have a todo property. So they're not going to show anything. Btw, it will be easier for people to understand your question if you make your nomenclature consistent—settle on either "task" or "todo" and then use that term consistently.

Comment: In the sample data you provided, you have two different objects within the task array. If idRoom had a valid value (which I'll assume it does), then it will likely choose the second object. That object doesn't have any todo prop.

Comment: Yop, that's what i was thinking, the second object doesn't have the todo property, thank you for y'all time !